# java.lang.ClassCastException: Servlet.Telnet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I want to implement a servlet and call it in a WebApp.

I am constantly get `java.lang.ClassCastException: Servlet.Telnet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet` from the Apache Tomcat Server. I made sure my class extends `HttpServlet` this is my code:

```
package Servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;




public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
             TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
             telnet.connect(request.getParameter("router"), 23);
             PrintStream output = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());
             output.println(request.getParameter("login"));
             output.flush();
             output.println(request.getParameter("password"));
             output.flush();
             out.printf("SUCCESS");



             telnet.disconnect();




        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.printf("ERROR");

        }
    }
```

Comment: why is your servlet an inner class

Comment: As a corollary, please try to format your question correctly. AT LEAST start your sentences with capital letters as a minimal sign of respect for those who are trying to help you.

Comment: `Servlet.Telnet` cannot be cast to `javax.servlet.Servlet`. This means that `Telnet` class in `Servlet` package is somewhere used. But we cannot see it in your code. Also provide more info from exception - at what line it happened and where is this line in your code

Comment: Bad choice of names. Servlet is an interface in the javax.servlet package. You should rename your package and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the package and the class and it works perfectly.